# Timer frequency for C64 CIA Timers?

Tags: c64

Can anyone confirm the frequency the C64 CIA 16bit timers tick  per second ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the C64, the 6526/8521 CIA chips run at the phase 2 system clock rate, which is set at either 0.985248MHz (PAL) or 1.022727Mhz (NTSC).

Comment: i suspected this but couldnt confirm :) thanx!

Comment: The 6526 datasheet is here, for further detailed information: http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6526_cia.pdf (don't forget to accept the answer if it resolved your query).